# syntax error near unexpected token `(' in .bashrc

Tags: bashrc, paths

```
-bash: /root/.bashrc: line 100: syntax error near unexpected token `('
-bash: /root/.bashrc: line 100: `export PATH=/bin/lscript:/bin/lscript:/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin:/usr/games:/usr/local/games:/mnt/c/Program Files/WindowsApps/CanonicalGroupLimited.UbuntuonWindows_1804.2019.521.0_x64__79rhkp1fndgsc:/mnt/c/Program Files (x86)/Common Files/Oracle/Java/javapath:/mnt/c/ProgramData/Oracle/Java/javapath:/mnt/c/Program Files (x86)/Intel/TXE Components/iCLS/:/mnt/c/Program Files/Intel/TXE Components/iCLS/:/mnt/c/WINDOWS/system32:/mnt/c/WINDOWS:/mnt/c/WINDOWS/System32/Wbem:/mnt/c/WINDOWS/System32/WindowsPowerShell/v1.0/:/mnt/c/Program Files/Intel/TXE Components/DAL/:/mnt/c/Program Files (x86)/Intel/TXE Components/DAL/:/mnt/c/Program Files/Intel/TXE Components/IPT/:/mnt/c/Program Files (x86)/Intel/TXE Components/IPT/:/mnt/c/Program Files/Intel/WiFi/bin/:/mnt/c/Program Files/Common Files/Intel/WirelessCommon/:/mnt/c/Program Files (x86)/GtkSharp/2.12/bin:/mnt/c/WINDOWS/System32/OpenSSH/:/mnt/c/Program Files (x86)/QuickTime/QTSystem/:/mnt/c/Program Files/PuTTY/:/mnt/c/Program Files/Git/cmd:/mnt/c/Program Files/Git/mingw64/bin:/mnt/c/Program Files/Git/usr/bin:/mnt/c/Users/User/AppData/Local/Microsoft/WindowsApps:/snap/bin'
```

Comment: The shell sees `export PATH=somethingsomething (x86)something` and compains, rightfully. Get in the habit of quoting strings which may contain spaces and other caracters which are special to the shell.

Comment: You've incorrectly modified your PATH statement and added an invalid path to some Windows directories. Not a good idea to mount your Windows C: drive and then access from Ubuntu anyway.

Comment: It seems you're using WSL.

Answer (score 0):

You have unquoted spaces in your value to be assigned. `bash` uses spaces to tell where one parameter ends and the next starts, and treats parenthesis ("`()`") as special. Thus,

> `` export PATH=/bin/lscript:/bin/lscript:/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin:/usr/games:/usr/local/games:/mnt/c/Program Files/WindowsApps/CanonicalGroupLimited.UbuntuonWindows_1804.2019.521.0_x64__79rhkp1fndgsc:/mnt/c/Program Files (x86)/Common Files/Oracle/Java/javapath:/mnt/c/ProgramData/Oracle/Java/javapath:/mnt/c/Program Files (x86)/Intel/TXE Components/iCLS/:/mnt/c/Program Files/Intel/TXE Components/iCLS/:/mnt/c/WINDOWS/system32:/mnt/c/WINDOWS:/mnt/c/WINDOWS/System32/Wbem:/mnt/c/WINDOWS/System32/Window`sPowerShell/v1.0/:/mnt/c/Program Files/Intel/TXE Components/DAL/:/mnt/c/Program Files (x86)/Intel/TXE Components/DAL/:/mnt/c/Program Files/Intel/TXE Components/IPT/:/mnt/c/Program Files (x86)/Intel/TXE Components/IPT/:/mnt/c/Program Files/Intel/WiFi/bin/:/mnt/c/Program Files/Common Files/Intel/WirelessCommon/:/mnt/c/Program Files (x86)/GtkSharp/2.12/bin:/mnt/c/WINDOWS/System32/OpenSSH/:/mnt/c/Program Files (x86)/QuickTime/QTSystem/:/mnt/c/Program Files/PuTTY/:/mnt/c/Program Files/Git/cmd:/mnt/c/Program Files/Git/mingw64/bin:/mnt/c/Program Files/Git/usr/bin:/mnt/c/Users/User/AppData/Local/Microsoft/WindowsApps:/snap/bin ``

looks like 32 parameters to `bash`'s assignment.

There are two solutions:

1. Escape each space or parenthesis with \.
2. Quote (`"` or `'`) each space-containing parameter.

Here's what using the first method gives:

```
export PATH=/bin/lscript:/bin/lscript:/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin:/usr/games:/usr/local/games:/mnt/c/Program\ Files/WindowsApps/CanonicalGroupLimited.UbuntuonWindows_1804.2019.521.0_x64__79rhkp1fndgsc:/mnt/c/Program\ Files\ \(x86\)/Common\ Files/Oracle/Java/javapath:/mnt/c/ProgramData/Oracle/Java/javapath:/mnt/c/Program\ Files\ \(x86\)/Intel/TXE\ Components/iCLS/:/mnt/c/Program\ Files/Intel/TXE\ Components/iCLS/:/mnt/c/WINDOWS/system32:/mnt/c/WINDOWS:/mnt/c/WINDOWS/System32/Wbem:/mnt/c/WINDOWS/System32/WindowsPowerShell/v1.0/:/mnt/c/Program\ Files/Intel/TXE\ Components/DAL/:/mnt/c/Program\ Files\ \(x86\)/Intel/TXE\ Components/DAL/:/mnt/c/Program\ Files/Intel/TXE\ Components/IPT/:/mnt/c/Program\ Files\ \(x86\)/Intel/TXE\ Components/IPT/:/mnt/c/Program\ Files/Intel/WiFi/bin/:/mnt/c/Program\ Files/Common\ Files/Intel/WirelessCommon/:/mnt/c/Program\ Files\ \(x86\)/GtkSharp/2.12/bin:/mnt/c/WINDOWS/System32/OpenSSH/:/mnt/c/Program\ Files\ \(x86\)/QuickTime/QTSystem/:/mnt/c/Program\ Files/PuTTY/:/mnt/c/Program\ Files/Git/cmd:/mnt/c/Program\ Files/Git/mingw64/bin:/mnt/c/Program\ Files/Git/usr/bin:/mnt/c/Users/User/AppData/Local/Microsoft/WindowsApps:/snap/bin
```

And, for the second method,

```
export PATH=/bin/lscript:/bin/lscript:/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin:/usr/games:/usr/local/games:"/mnt/c/Program Files/WindowsApps/CanonicalGroupLimited.UbuntuonWindows_1804.2019.521.0_x64__79rhkp1fndgsc":"/mnt/c/Program Files (x86)/Common Files/Oracle/Java/javapath":/mnt/c/ProgramData/Oracle/Java/javapath:"/mnt/c/Program Files (x86)/Intel/TXE Components/iCLS/":"/mnt/c/Program Files/Intel/TXE Components/iCLS/":/mnt/c/WINDOWS/system32:/mnt/c/WINDOWS:/mnt/c/WINDOWS/System32/Wbem:/mnt/c/WINDOWS/System32/WindowsPowerShell/v1.0/:"/mnt/c/Program Files/Intel/TXE Components/DAL/":"/mnt/c/Program Files (x86)/Intel/TXE Components/DAL/":"/mnt/c/Program Files/Intel/TXE Components/IPT/":"/mnt/c/Program Files (x86)/Intel/TXE Components/IPT/":"/mnt/c/Program Files/Intel/WiFi/bin/":"/mnt/c/Program Files/Common Files/Intel/WirelessCommon/":"/mnt/c/Program Files (x86)/GtkSharp/2.12/bin":/mnt/c/WINDOWS/System32/OpenSSH/:"/mnt/c/Program Files (x86)/QuickTime/QTSystem/":"/mnt/c/Program Files/PuTTY/":"/mnt/c/Program Files/Git/cmd":"/mnt/c/Program Files/Git/mingw64/bin":"/mnt/c/Program Files/Git/usr/bin":/mnt/c/Users/User/AppData/Local/Microsoft/WindowsApps:/snap/bin
```

Comment: Parentheses must also be escaped in the first method I think? that's why the error is `unexpected token '('` rather than something like `'/mnt/c/Program': No such file or directory`